# passing argument to callback function listening on argumnets

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

```
function setmclisten(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(data);
  if(message['type'] === 'startUp')
  {
    console.log(data);
    sendResponse(data)
  }
}
function QuarryToServer(){
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(setmclisten);
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    form: 'formatted',
    url: SERVERURL,
    success: function (data) {
      //sends a get 
      console.log("set startup listener");
      debugger;
      chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(setmclisten);
    },
    fail: function () { console.error("error quarrying server"); }
  });
}
```

the problem im encountring i need the function to be named so i can remove the listener later on  but when i make it a named function i cant access the data variable and if i try to pass it like addListen(func(args)) it will just call the function instead of passing it as a variable is there a way to pass the variable and at the same time still have the function defined in the global scope
to clarify:so theres the setmclisten and i need it to be a named function and at the same time pass the data argument and recive the onmessge listener arugments like the messge it self

Comment: *"...when i make it a named function i cant access the data variable..."* Why not? And what function are you talking about?

Comment: so theres the setmclisten and i need it to be a named function and at the same time pass the data argument and recive the onmessge listener arugments like the messge it self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the problem. With more context we may be able to help you solve it in a better way, but the minimal changes approach is to remember the last listener, like this (see `***` comments):

```
function setmclisten(message, sender, sendResponse, data) { // *** Note `data` param
                                                            // at end
  console.log(data);
  if(message['type'] === 'startUp')
  {
    console.log(data);
    sendResponse(data)
  }
}
let lastListener = null; // *** Remember the last listener
function QuarryToServer(){
  // *** Remove the last listener if any
  if (lastListener) {
      chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(lastListener);
      lastListener = null;
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    form: 'formatted',
    url: SERVERURL,
    success: function (data) {
      //sends a get 
      console.log("set startup listener");
      // *** Create a new listener and attach it
      lastListener = function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
          return setmclisten(message, sender, sendResponse, data);
          // *** Or if `this` is important in the call:
          // return setmclisten.call(this, message, sender, sendResponse, data);
      };
      chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(lastListener);
    },
    fail: function () { console.error("error quarrying server"); }
  });
}
```

---

Alternatively, always have a listener attached rather than adding and removing it, and have it use the latest data:

```
let lastData = null; // ***
function setmclisten(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (!lastData) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(lastData);
  if(message['type'] === 'startUp')
  {
    console.log(lastData);
    sendResponse(lastData)
  }
}
function QuarryToServer(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    form: 'formatted',
    url: SERVERURL,
    success: function (data) {
      lastData = data; // ***
    },
    fail: function () { console.error("error quarrying server"); }
  });
}
```

In the above, I assume you do

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(setmclisten);
```

once.